# Review button disappears upon loading of the screen

Tags: bug, design

When I load the homepage of SO on my mobile-phone, using the responsive view, (Chrome on Android) there is the products link in place since a few days now. Interestingly since that is appearing there is something strange going on with the review queue's button. It appears during loading, but as the final step in loading the button disappears from the screen again.

I don't think this behaviour was in place before the products link was there. This happens whenever I refresh a page. Screen size is 2240x1080p.

Screen during loading:

[image: During loading]

Screen when loading is finished:

[image: Finished loading]

Looking at the first screenshot there appears to be a scollbar in the topbar of the page. From the top right corner until halfway in the topbar. So something in the responsiveness is being rendered upon loading, instead of prior to loading I assume?

Comment: I am not sure that's a scrollbar, but a loading progress indicator.

Comment: @yivi the blue is indeed a progressindicator. But looking at the right edge of the screen there appears to be a grayish scrollbar, from the top right corner untill halfway the topbar

Comment: Seems [by-design] to me. I'm guessing you are running the "desktop"-responsive version on mobile? When there isn't space in the top bar, the help, reviews, mod flag count buttons disappear in that order to make more space.

Comment: @SamuelLiew correct, since the mobile version is just c̵r̵*̵p̵ not a real version. If you look at the first screenshot there is plenty of room for 4 buttons, even 5 if the very unhelpful products link is removed. Why does it have to resize to less buttons, and why does it has to happen in a visual way. It's not like it is a mystery at what width the site is being rendered while it starts...

Comment: @SamuelLiew The product button is about 2.5 times wider than those buttons.  Why not just hide it?  ...

Comment: Yes the same case for me, the button disappeared. I discussed it with CodyGray in a comment thread.

Comment: What's the screensize in actual pixels? Because what you listed is probably device pixels and is obviously more than large enough to show all the buttons as a true resolution. Unless you meant to type 240x1080, instead?

Comment: Anyway, it looks like class `.d-none` is being added to the `li.-item` for that review icon at widths of 290px or less. Seems like it'd be better to hide the SO icon instead and show review (as there's plenty of ways to get back to the questions lists already), but then who would want to review posts on such an ill-fitting form factor?

Comment: @tylerH, I don't know how I got the pixel size, probably from googling my device. Which lists as resolution FHD+ (2240*1080). Screensize is 6.1". And viewport is listed as 360*747. The last would then be the actual pixels I imagine?

Comment: @TylerH and reviewing goes quiet well on such a small screen, usually I default to inline view, unless some coding has been changed then I switch to side by side. On inline view the view is hardly any different from reading a question on mobile.

Comment: @Luuklag 360x747 is probably your actual pixels, yeah. The 1080 FHD number is device pixels that are virtual pixels used to give you a higher resolution experience with a smaller screen. That would probably be where it disappears for most people (I have a custom style on my computer that removes the "Products" menu entirely, which probably accounts for the extra 70px between your resolution and where I found it to disappear for me).